# ¿Como consigo crear una GUI en COSMOS User Kit?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un sistema operativo que se llama RaxOS en COSMOS y he seguido muchos tutoriales para poner GUIs y no funcionan, probé `Cosmos.Hardware.VGAScreen screen;` en el class pero sale error: no existe el namespace Cosmos.Hardware, y `screen.SetMode 300x200x8() y , obviamente me dice que screen no existe` probé `Canvas canvas` en el class y en BeforeRun();

```
canvas = FullScreenCanvas.GetFullScreenCanvas();
canvas.Clear(Color.Black);
```

con esto: `Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White);` en el Run(); pero no consigo que me muestre un GUI

Comment: Lo he intentado TODO